# Realtime sound post-processing, sound effects, Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: audio, ubuntu-10.04, alsa

I'm looking for a way to apply manually controlled effects, like echo or pitch change, or equalizer, to the entire sound output in Ubuntu. I'm thinking about something similar to what *Creative SB Live!* software can do on Windows. The effects should affect all applications playing sounds in the system, and preferably should be controlled via GUI. Should I be investigating the direction of ALSA plugins (which I know nothing about at the moment)?

Answer (score 3):

Pulseaudio [supports](http://www.pulseaudio.org/wiki/Modules#module-ladspa-sink) some LADSPA plugins.

```
sudo aptitude install rlwrap swh-plugins
rlwrap pacmd
# equalizer
load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=ladspa_out plugin=mbeq_1197 label=mbeq control=11.621622,10,4.594594,2.702703,0,0,-1.621622,-0.270270,-5.405406,-3.513514,-8.648648,-5.675676,-4.054054,1.351351,9.189189
# volume compression
load-module module-ladspa-sink sink_name=sc4m plugin=sc4m_1916 label=sc4m control=1,1.5,401,-30,20,5,12
set-default-sink sc4m
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! But, there seems to be no way to control parameters at run time. Maximum I appear to be able to achieve is to pre-configure some presets, loaded with different names, and switch between them using gnome-volume-control. Is there a better way?

Comment: @atzz: There are some hints on [pulseaudio - Is there a way of leveling/compressing the sound system-wide? - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31580/is-there-a-way-of-leveling-compressing-the-sound-system-wide/44012#44012). I see parameters appear in alsamixer but they don't seem to affect the sound real-time.